# Trying to add a Date column to table, but getting MSG 156 Incorrect syntax near the keyword error

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

I'm attempting to create a column which calculates the date based on the start date and a week count column. Below is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE Salesforce_Expanded
    ADD current_date DATE;
GO

UPDATE Salesforce_Expanded
SET current_date = DATEADD(week, Week_Count-1, start_date);
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'current_date'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'current_date'.

Comment: [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Try using`[current_date]` or `CurrentDate`; Alternatively consider _not_ storing data that can be derived from an existing column, use a *computed column*

Comment: oh wow... I feel so dumb! Thanks! I Just renamed the column and it worked!

Comment: this will work: 
ALTER TABLE Salesforce_Expanded
    ADD [current_date] Date null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a *computed column* here.

The problem with adding and updating values in a new column is that you now have a value that is *dependent* on existing data; it is possible to update any of the other dependent columns in isolation and then `current_date` is immediately invalid or corrupted data.

You *could* enforce maintaining the value via a trigger, however a better solution would be to implement a computed column, which will always be correct.

```
Alter table Salesforce_Expanded
add [Current_Date] as DATEADD(week, Week_Count-1, start_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I was using a Reserved Keyword as the name of the column. Changing the name of the column fixed the issue.